# Algorithm for sorting an array of points on their concentration

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computational-geometry

I have array of coordinates, and I wish to sort it by concentration zone of points. I have tried using Graham algorithm, (shown below,) but I do not get the desired result. What algorithm can I use to make the point sorted as shown in this image:

[image]

Source:

```
def rotate(A,B,C):
return (B[0]-A[0])*(C[1]-B[1])-(B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-B[0])

def grahamscan(A):
    n = len(A) 
    P = range(n) 
    for i in range(1,n):
      if A[P[i]][0]<A[P[0]][0]: 
         P[i], P[0] = P[0], P[i] 
for i in range(2,n): 
  j = i
  while j>1 and (rotate(A[P[0]],A[P[j-1]],A[P[j]])<0): 
     P[j], P[j-1] = P[j-1], P[j]
     j -= 1
S = [P[0],P[1]] 
for i in range(2,n):
  while rotate(A[S[-2]],A[S[-1]],A[P[i]])<0:
    del S[-1] # pop(S)
    S.append(P[i]) # push(S,P[i])
return S
```

Comment: What are your time constraints?  How big do you expect the data set to be?

Comment: I want to do this task before the end of the week. The data size is in the range 1 - near 5000 coordinates.

Comment: I should have said "runtime constraints".  How do you want to define "concentration zone"?

Comment: The question is not clear: do you want to cluster your data by density then sort the data by the number of points/cluster volume ?

Comment: Graham scan is a convex hull algorithm and not appropriate for what you are doing. Although after you known what the clusters should be, then running it on the clusters would provide the convex hulls of the clusters which would look similar to the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of [clusterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). 
Try [K_Means method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) at first.

Comment: Yah, I thought it might be NP-hard, which is why I was asking about runtime and data size.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I implemented a proprietary algorithm (although it may already exist) for my case (see below).

Source (Objective C):

```
static inline NSArray* clustering (NSArray *aSetOfPoint, CGFloat radius, CGFloat delta) {

NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aSetOfPoint.copy];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

while (data.count > 0) {

  NSMutableArray *cluster = [NSMutableArray new];

  NSArray *zeroPoint = data[0];
  for (NSArray *aPoint in data) {
     if ([zeroPoint[0] floatValue] > [aPoint[0] floatValue]) {
        zeroPoint = aPoint;
     }
  }
  [cluster addObject:zeroPoint];
  [data removeObject:zeroPoint];

  CGPoint zeroCoordinate = CGPointMake([zeroPoint[0] floatValue], [zeroPoint[1] floatValue]);
  __block CGRect clusterRect = CGRectMake(zeroCoordinate.x, zeroCoordinate.y-radius, radius, 2 * radius);
  __block int count = 1;
  while (count > 0) {
     count =0;
     NSMutableArray *clusteringData = data.copy;

     [clusteringData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *aPoint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (aPoint) {
           CGPoint aCoordinate = CGPointMake([aPoint[0] floatValue], [aPoint[1] floatValue]);

           if (CGRectContainsPoint(clusterRect, aCoordinate)) {
              [cluster addObject:aPoint];
              [data removeObject:aPoint];
              count++;
           }
        }
     }];

     clusterRect = CGRectMake(zeroCoordinate.x, zeroCoordinate.y - delta, clusterRect.size.width + delta, clusterRect.size.height + 2 * delta);
  }
  if (cluster.count == 1) {
     [cluster addObject:cluster[0]];
  }
  [result addObject:cluster];
}

  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```